# ios8 webview with webgl = smooth scrolling in web apps?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, uiwebview, webgl

I was at an html5 meetup recently, and heard another attendee say that ios8 webview has webgl and as a result, web apps (with phonegap) will finally have smooth scrolling. From googling around, it seems that webgl is a graphics library usually used for 3d stuff. Is that correct? If so, how would it have any effect on scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

webgl is a hardware accelerated low level API for the HTML canvas element that allows drawing of 3D and 2D graphics. It doesn't have any direct effect on the scrolling of web pages. However most scrolling effects involve a lot of elements being animated on the page based on scroll events. There could be performance gains by throwing some of this content onto a hardware accelerated webgl context, rather than the DOM. This would avoid layout calculations and other performance overhead. However, this can add another level of complexity to the web application. Of course this would all depend on the content (what is taking place while a user scrolls) and the performance of webGL on the device.